# C++ API exception: std::length_error

Tags: c++, dolphindb

I used VS2019 and the compilation passed, but when I call the conn.connect() function, the following error occurred:

unhandled exception: Microsoft C++ exception: std::length_error, located at memory 0x0000000B5DAFF340.

What’s going on here?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/length_error

Answer (score 0):

The exception is usually caused by the following operations:

1. Inconsistent behavior across compilers. For example, compling the
   DLL with MinGW but the EXE with VS2019; compiling the DLL with g++
   but compiling the EXE with VS2019
2. Inconsistent compilation options or linked external library versions
   of DLL and EXE. For example, the openSSL version, the STL version,
   etc.

You can refer to the environment configuration and compilation on Windows:
https://github.com/dolphindb/api-cplusplus/blob/master/README.md

If the problem still exists, please send us the VS2019 configuration file to solve the problem.